Identify unknown 2014 horror movie
Looking for the name of a 2014 horror movie that I'm 95% sure was released on or immediately prior to halloween. All i remember is a scene from the trailer. It involves people discussing the ghost of a little girl, along the lines of "she's not what she says/you think she is" then the girl ghost is shown as a door closes obscuring the camera, then an angry adult ghost comes running out. I believe the title was a name (Not Annabell or Jessabelle). 
Edit: The people in the trailer if i recall correctly KNOW the little girl is a ghost that lives in (I think) the bathroom. There is a college age guy with dark/black hair as well as one or two women.

maybe Mama http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2023587/?ref_=nv_sr_1 ?

Nope, Mama came out in January of 13, but thank you for the reply.

Is it Ouija (2014)?? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1204977/

Are we just tossing out titles at this point? ;) @Tileus I don't think there was a name-based horror movie released around Halloween 2014 besides Annabelle (at least not in theaters).

There is an horror miniseries released in 2013 Haunting Melissa; a trailer of the sequel was released in november 2014: its site is http://darkhearts-hauntingmelissa2.tumblr.com/

Could it be 'The Quiet Ones'? - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2235779/
It came out last year, and was about a poltergeist that had possessed a young girl. Set in England in the 1960's, it starred Jared Harris and Sam Claflin, who could be the dark haired college aged boy you mention.
It's quite an effective chiller, and was part of Hammer Horrors 'revival' series of films.
